# Me sale error al guardar los datos, Error : No se encontro el procedimiento almacenado 'ActualizaArticulos'?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public partial class MantenimientoProducto : Mantenimiento
{
    public MantenimientoProducto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public override bool guardar()
    {
        try
        {
            string cmd = string.Format("EXEC ActualizaArticulos '{0}','{1}','{2}'", idproducto.Text.Trim(), descripcion.Text.Trim(), precio.Text.Trim());
            utilidades.ejecutar(cmd);
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha guardo Satisfactoriamente");
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + error.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Existe ese procedimiento almacenado en tu base de datos?

Comment: si el procedimiento esta dentro de la base de datos.

Comment: Probablemente lo escribiste mal en tu código

Comment: podria yo mandarte el codigo de sql para que lo veas?

Comment: Puedes hacer la prueba en tu motor de base de datos llamandolo via consulta sql

Comment: Como haria para llamarlo?

Comment: Un query en el management studio debería permitirte saber si el método realmente existe.

Comment: en el caso de mysql es CALL nombre_storeprocedure(parametro1, parametro2) para Sql server debe ser EXEC nombre_storeprocedure(parametro1, parametro2)